# Error Running command shell :TimeoutError Operation Time out

Tags: linux, metasploit, shellcode

I am Testing a Payload linux/x86/meterpreter/reverse_tcp in my Test Linux network to Exploit, I got a Meterpreter Session by Metasploit using it, I tried several commands like getuid, cat and all those are working fine, But the command `shell` is not working, it means i am Unable to create a shell session from that, I am getting an Error which says

`[-] Error running command shell: Rex:: TimeoutError Operation Timed Out`

My Server is Running Architecture is `x86_64` Which means a 64 bit OS, And i am using a x86 payload . So does it caused problem in shell command? And i am unable to Find a Reverse_TCP 64 Bit payload in Linux Modules , Can anyone help me out, or give exact reasons why the error is outputting ?

Moreover while Pivoting the Reverse_tcp Should run command ifconfig but in x86 OS System, the `shell` gives Channel of 
`sh-4.2$ ifconfig command not found`

Comment: yes, using the wrong architecture will cause problems - did you know about https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/payload/generic/shell_reverse_tcp ?

Comment: if python is installed, try:

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following to spawn a bash shell:

```
execute -i -f /bin/bash
```